# is there any easy way to use a sum function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 50 |

how to add the column rows in Power BI by using a sum function or which is the best function to use, mostly what I get is an error. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this.

First using a calculated column would be:

```
Total = 'Table'[A1] + 'Table'[A2] + 'Table'[A3] + 'Table'[A4] + 'Table'[A5]
```

[image: Calculated Column]

Second and best option would be a to unpivot the data in the query editor, which gives two columns 'Attribute' and 'Value' which you can rename and use a measure:

```
Measure = SUM('Table'[Value])
```

[image: Pivoted table]

You could also use a measure and the matrix visual rather than pivot the table,

```
Measure = SUM('Table'[A1]) + SUM('Table'[A2]) + SUM('Table'[A3]) + SUM('Table'[A4]) + SUM('Table'[A5])
```

[image: Matrix visual]

As mentioned option 2 is the best option, particularly if you what to chart the data and use a slicer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with DAX function SUMX
Below is the proper sytnax:

MeassureName = SUMX(TableName, TableName[column a] +TableName[column b] +TableName[column c] ...)